# why can't I dereference an iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

If I have a vector of objects (plain objects, not pointers or references), why can't I do this?

```
Object* object;

object = vectorOfObjects.end();
```

or

```
object = &vectorOfObjects.end();
```

or

```
object = &(*vectorOfObjects.end());
```

also the same question if 'object' was a reference.

Comment: I assume you didn't mean to declare object as a pointer after explicitly saying your objects were by value?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are three separate errors:

```
object = vectorOfObjects.end();
```

won't work because `end()` returns a an iterator, and `object` is a pointer. Those are generally distinct types (A vector *can* use raw pointers as iterators, but not all implementations do it. Other containers require special iterator types).

```
object = &vectorOfObjects.end();
```

doesn't work because you take the address of the returned iterator. That is, you get a pointer to an iterator, rather than a pointer to an `Object`.

```
object = &(*vectorOfObjects.end());
```

doesn't work because the `end` iterator doesn't point to a valid element. It points one past the end of the sequence. And so, it can't be dereferenced. You can dereference the last element in the sequence (which would be `--vectorOfObjects.end()`), but not an iterator pointing *past* the end.

Finally, the underlying problem/confusion might be that you think an iterator can be converted to a pointer. In general, it can't. If your container is a vector, you're guaranteed that elements are allocated contiguously, like in an array, and so a pointer will work. But for, say, a  `list`, a pointer to an element is useless. It doesn't give you any way to reach the *next* element.

Answer (score 7):

Because `.end()` returns an iterator, not an `Object`, which isn't even a valid member of the vector.

Even using `begin()`, which returns a valid object, you'd need the following:

The correct way would be:

```
std::vector<Object> vec;
std::vector<Object>::iterator it;
//....
it = vec.begin();
Object o = *it;
```

Comment: if (it!=vec.end() {o=*it;}

Answer (score 3):

This is because by convention `end` does not point to a valid location in the container: it sits at a location one past the end of the container, so dereferencing it is illegal.

The situation with `begin()` is different: you can dereference it when `v.begin() != v.end()` (i.e. when the container is not empty):

```
object = *vectorOfObjects.begin();
```

If you need to access the last element, you can do this:

```
vector<object>::const_iterator i = vectorOfObjects.end();
i--;
cout << *i << endl; // Prints the last element of the container
```

Again, this works only when your vector contains at least one element.

Comment: Even if you use .begin, it won't work, the real reason is it return an iterator, which is a different type of the object

Comment: @lzprgmr That's why I added an asterisk to actually *dereference* the iterator, like the question title says :)

Comment: Is start() a typo for begin() ?

Comment: @MickaëlG Yes, of course it is! Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

Object* means a pointer to an Object, where a pointer is a memory address.  But the .end() method returns an Iterator, which is an object itself, not a memory address.